# Where can I get list of all properties supported by event.target? Is there a property like event.target.search?

Tags: angular

I know that chrome developer tool, gives an exhaustive list of all the properties of element, when we select any form inspect element. What I need is, segregated properties applicable for specific element case by case.

Also is there event.target.search apples to any of the element.
For example in case of event.target.pathname, if we check below,

Html,

```
<a href="catalog/testpages/test2.html" onClick="targetTest()" title="test page" />
```

Script,

```
function targetTest(event) {
 console.log(event.target.pathname); 
}
```

console output,
catalog/testpages/test2.html

Similarly is there 'event.target.search' related to any specific element attribute?
I have seen this in one of the code and never got console output on clicking of all the available elements including `<input type="search" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check in the debugging tool in Inspect Element, try to hover element.target and you should get a list of functions available.

Comment: I checked all the options for various elements in the Inspect Element but I didn't got anything related to 'event.target.search'. I also checked documentation on methods available for event.target, but didn't got any reference for search there.